# Using a custom MSSQL query in spring

Tags: sql-server, spring

I'm trying to run a custom query in spring with an MSSQL DB:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT my_id, date, name " +
    "FROM my_events " +
    "WHERE name == :name " +
    "AND date between :starttime and :endtime " +
    "ORDER BY date DESC",
    nativeQuery = true)
List<myDAO> findByNameAndDateBetweenOrderByDateDesc (
    @Param("name")String name,
    @Param("starttime")String starttime,
    @Param("endtime")String endtime
);
```

When running the application without the custom query I'm getting:

```
Name for parameter binding must not be null or empty! On JDKs < 8, you need to use @Param for named parameters, on JDK 8 or better, be sure to compile with -parameters.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for parameter binding must not be null or empty! On JDKs < 8, you need to use @Param for named parameters, on JDK 8 or better, be sure to compile with -parameters.
```

When running the application without the @Query annotation (using the CrudRepository) it works fine.

The query will be changed to a more complicated query once I figure out the simplified one above, this is why I can't use the CrudRepository function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this ticket: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1086.
Same error was resolved by adding maven plugin:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArgument>-parameters</compilerArgument>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```